# Make View Clickable after Animation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

After animation I'm not able to click on view. I search alot about this and read answers on stackoverflow and found something that animation only draw raw pixels. To make view clickable you must need to move view. So I write some code but this is not working fine.
Here is my code.

**anim.xml**

```
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="-50%p"
    android:duration="500" />
```

**MainActivity**

```
  Animation anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim);
  anim.setAnimationListener(animLintener);
  imageView.startAnimation(anim);

  private Animation.AnimationListener animLintener= new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            int widthHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int marginBottom = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 36, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int marginLeft = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 36, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    deactivateParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(widthHeight, widthHeight);
    deactivateParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    deactivateParams.bottomMargin = marginBottom;
    deactivateParams.leftMargin = marginLeft;

    imageView.setLayoutParams(deactivateParams);
    }
  }
```

Problem with this code is that after running `onAnimationEnd` animation changed from it's position. Why this is happening. I think once animation complete it will move any further, Right ?
Please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: can you explain your question? last two lines are confusing me.

Comment: @RachitSolanki I edit my question can you please check it again

Comment: @RachitSolanki simply I want to make `imageView` clickable after animation.

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong but after animation ends your imageview position changes but not the clickable area am i getting right ?

Comment: Yes right, That's way I try to change the position of imageview where the animation move.

Comment: This is the normal behavior of the Animation class, it will only move view but the actual placing will still remains, use object animator instead.

Comment: @RachitSolanki how I implement objectAnimator in my case

Comment: @RachitSolanki your mean objectAnimator also  move actual view ? Is it click able after animation